# Should we make a 2048 tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Currently, we have at least 12 [questions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+title%3A2048) relating to the game [2048](https://play2048.co/). I think it would be worth creating a [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) tag, as there are a non-insignificant number of these questions now. We have tags for other games, like [chess](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), [boggle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boggle), [scrabble](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble) (many of which have fewer than 10 questions), so there is precedent for these sorts of tags existing.

There is a [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) tag, which includes 2048 (this is stated clearly in the excerpt). However, less than half of the 2048 related questions use this tag, and it's not very "discoverable" to those writing questions involving the game.

I'd suggest either creating a [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) tag and possibly making some adjustments to [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle)'s scope if needed, or just making [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048), as a synonym of it. What do y'all think about this?

Answer (score 12):

#### Make [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048) an explicit synonym of [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle), retag challenges that need [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle)

I think it's clear that [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) fully covers [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048), as all challenges about 2048 are applicable to [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle), but there may be challenges about tile games that aren't specifically about 2048.

However, you raise an excellent point about not enough questions being tagged with [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle). This is a perfect example of when we should be doing some retagging and editing this tag into applicable questions.

Finally, by explicitly creating the synonym [2048](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/2048), it means that any new challenges about it can easily find the [sliding-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sliding-puzzle) tag, and that, like e.g. [koth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koth), we have the tag in the system ready to help find and retag relevant challenges.

Answer (score -4):

## Yes

You can add 2048 tag.